# Dividing elements of one list by elements of another list

Tags: python, numpy

I have a lists `A=[1, 1, 1, 1]` and `B=[2, 3, 4, 5]`, and I want to define `C=[50%, 33%, 25%, 20%]` (i.e. I'm dividing each element of A by the corresponding element of B and then multiplying each by 100 to get the percentage).

When trying to find out how to do the division I came across: [Dividing elements of one list by elements of another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48990152/dividing-elements-of-one-list-by-elements-of-another) but this case is much more complex than what I need so I got really confused.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps consider `numpy`? Any reason not to?

Comment: `np.round(np.divide(A,B),2)*100` as @ALollz mentioned , also removing pandas as it is not related to pandas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
C = [a/b*100 for a, b in zip(A,B)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
c = [a / b * 100 for (a, b) in zip(A, B)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You may abstract away your operations with own classes and a dunder function:

```
class AdvancedList(list):

    def __truediv__(self, other):
        result = [x / y for x, y in zip(self, other)]
        return result


A = AdvancedList([1, 1, 1, 1])
B = AdvancedList([2, 3, 4, 5])
print(A / B)
```

Which yields

```
[0.5, 0.3333333333333333, 0.25, 0.2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for i in range(len(A)):
    A[i] = str(A[i]/B[i] * 100) + "%"
```

Answer (score 0):

convert it to string....`xx%`

```
result = ["%.0f%%"%(a*100 / b) for a, b in zip(A, B)]
# ['50%', '33%', '25%', '20%']
```

Attention:if you don't want to round this number,

```
result = ["%.d%%"%(a*100 / b) for a, b in zip(A, B)]
```